# RowSelect event p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Need to capture the rowSelect event of a dataTable having checkbox based row selection.
The code is as follows:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{articleBean.onRowSelect}"
                    oncomplete="articleBean.onSelection" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{articleBean.onRowUnselect}"
                    oncomplete="articleBean.onSelection" />
<p:column id="name" headerText="Select" selectionMode="multiple"
                    style="width:18px" />
```

I'm unable to understand the behavior. When I click checkbox for the first time, the method "onRowSelect" is getting called. When I unselect, "onRowUnselect" is not getting called. And also, the "onRowSelect" method is called just once for the grid, as in, if I click any other checkbox, the event is not getting triggered. Am I missing out anything? Not able to understand this behavior.

Comment: Does it work if you refresh the page after the first selection?

Comment: @Matt  Yes, it works for the first selection after getting refreshed.

Comment: I don't see any update command in your `p:ajax`. So only the current element will be updated. You could try to set `update="@form"` if this is possible in your case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you are using dataTable with checkbox based row selection then you should replace:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect"
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect"
```

With the following:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox"
```

Comment: Is there also an event for "select all" via checkbox in dataTable header? These `rowSelectCheckbox` and `rowUnselectCheckbox` events don't work in this case.

Comment: Okay the event is `toggleSelect` (When header checkbox is toggled.)